# How do you run a select statement in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework, using the connection string in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been searching all day and only find pieces of what I need and can't find a complete and SIMPLE example of what the model, controller, and view should look like to run even a simple select statement using the database defined in my `web.config`.

Could some one please show me an example of what the model, view, controller should look like for this? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext(); // This is your database connection referenced in the web.config  

    public ActionResult test() 
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM..."; // finish your query here
        int count = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).Single();
        return View(count); // pass your count to the view
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model int
<div>
@Model.ToString()
</div>
```

In this example the Model is an int, but you could use any custom model you came up with (and it should match the fields in the SELECT statement).

EDIT

Added code for the database connection:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    //: base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 6000;
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Put that in a Model file (usually it'll be in your IdentityModels, depending on how your project was generated).

Comment: Thanks @ScottDellinger, I keep have the problem, though, of "db" not being found in this context and not resolving. Has a red underline in VisualStudio. What am I missing?

Comment: How did you get the connection string in your web.config? Did you create an entity model (edmx) and then that auto-added it to your config? Or did you manually add it? If you create an entity model, it should create all of the underlying data classes, and add the connection string to the web.config. This is what you want to do.

Comment: @ahartman89 I've added code to show the database connection to the answer.